# Cannot connect to MySQL Docker container from another machine on Mac OS X

Tags: mysql, macos, docker

I use Mac OS X 10.9.

I have  `mysqld` service installed, and listen at `127.0.0.1:3306`.

```
$ netstat -Lan|grep 3306
0/0/80         127.0.0.1.3306
```

I want to deploy one more mysqld in docker container and will connect here from other containers as well as host machine command line.

Create MySQL container:

```
docker run --name mysql_1 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret -d mysql:latest -p 3306:3306
```

But I'm unable to connect it from host machine:

```
$ docker-machine ip default
192.168.99.100

$ docker ps -a|grep mysql
138f33b27756        mysql:latest        "docker-entrypoint.sh"   About an hour ago   Exited (1) About an hour ago    

               mysql_1

$ mysql -h 192.168.99.100 
    ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.99.100' (61)
```

Comment: The container is not running: `Exited (1) About an hour ago`.